# Printing an array into a table using a foreach loop. html/php

Tags: php, html

Programming assignment, Create a text area for a User to enter in lines of text then Print the text into a table with the item and and the item number.

The item is ended by a new line character/return character and the number of items should be counted and displayed in the table.

I'm believe my issue is somewhere inside the foreach loop but can not seem to find a solution.

Any help would be great thanks.

```css
<!doctype html>
<META HTTPEQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta httpequiv="expires" content="0" />
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hw7.css">
</head>
<body>
<?

$text = $_POST['stuff'];

$wordlist = explode("PHP_EOL", $text);
$wordcount = count($text);


print '<table>
  <tr>
 <th>Item Number</th>
 <th>Item</th>
  </tr>
';

//asort($wordlist);
foreach ($wordlist as $wordlists){
 
print " <tr>
      <td> $wordcount <br/> </td> 
      <td> $wordlists <br/> </td>   
     </tr>";
 
print '</table>'; 
}


 

?>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hw7.css">
</head>
<body>

<section id="info">
Enter a list of valuse or text to sort in the textbox to the right. <br/> <br/>

<ul>
<li>Value sort will sort each individual line.</li> <br/>
<li>Text sort will sort each individual word.</li>
</ul>

</section>

<form action="hw7.php" method="post">
<section id="items">
<textarea rows="20" cols="40" name="stuff" >
</textarea> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sort!">
</section>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP_EOL is a constant.  If you encapsulate it in quotes it becomes a string. So try this in your explode().

```
$wordlist = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
```

Comment: Another thing `count($text);` wont return the number of words in a string.  It will return however, the number of elements in an array.